# For any positive integer n, let d(n) denote the number of positive divisors of n; and let φ(n) denote the

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

For any positive integer n, let d(n) denote the number of positive divisors of n; and let
φ(n) denote the number of elements from the set {1, 2, · · · , n} that are coprime to n.
(For example, d(12) = 6 and φ(12) = 4.)
Find the smallest positive integer n such that d(φ(n)) = 2017.

I have arrived at the stage wherein p^2016=φ(n) 
What shall I do next?
Why cannot p=1;φ(n)=1 and then n will be equal to 1.
The answer is actually  2^2017

Comment: $p$ is a prime, $1$ isn't. Also, $d(1) = 1$.

Comment: First, identify $p$, to know exactly what $\varphi(n)$ is. Then consider the possible prime factorisations for numbers with the given totient.

Comment: so p must be 2 then ?

Comment: Can you say why?

Comment: It is the first positive prime  , and we are trying to find the smallest n?

Comment: That's an argument for "$p$ is probably $2$", but do you know why it absolutely positively unquestionably _must_ be $2$?

Comment: No ,could you tell me why

Comment: For $k > 2$, $\varphi(k)$ is even. Thus we know $\varphi(n) = 2^{2016}$. Okay, what does that tell us about the prime factorisation of $n$?

Comment: Why can't φ(k) be even?

Comment: I suppose you meant to write "odd" rather than "even" there. The most elementary way to see that totients are always even when they're larger than $1$ notes that $\gcd(a,k) = \gcd(k-a,k)$, so we can pair each $a < k/2$ with $\gcd(a,k) = 1$ with a unique $b > k/2$ with $\gcd(b,k) = 1$. If $k$ is an even integer larger than $2$, then $\gcd(k, k/2) = k/2 > 1$, hence the only integer that _would_ be paired with itself is not one of the integers coprime to $k$.

Comment: Patience is a great virtue. But it doesn't always help.

Comment: @DanielFischer  a search for small primes in $d(\phi(n)) = p$ suggests  that the only way to beat $2^p$ is with a product of distinct Fermat primes. Unless $p$ is itself a Fermat prime...

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, that's the only imaginable way. But $2^{32} + 1$ isn't prime, so it doesn't work for $2^{2016}$.

Answer (score -1):

Just looking for patterns. It seems that there is often one value $n$ that gives $d(\phi(n)) = p$  where $n$ is a little smaller than the power of $2$ that works. However, this number $n$ is a Fermat prime or the product of  Fermat primes. So, if you can prove that, you probably have it.

=================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   3" mse.txt | head -3
5 =  5   prime:   3
8 =  2^3   prime:   3
10 =  2 5   prime:   3
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   5" mse.txt | head -3
17 =  17   prime:   5
32 =  2^5   prime:   5
34 =  2 17   prime:   5
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   7" mse.txt | head -3
85 =  5 17   prime:   7
128 =  2^7   prime:   7
136 =  2^3 17   prime:   7
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   11" mse.txt | head -3
1285 =  5 257   prime:   11
2048 =  2^11   prime:   11
2056 =  2^3 257   prime:   11
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   13" mse.txt | head -3
4369 =  17 257   prime:   13
8192 =  2^13   prime:   13
8224 =  2^5 257   prime:   13
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   17" mse.txt | head -3
65537 =  65537   prime:   17
131072 =  2^17   prime:   17
131074 =  2 65537   prime:   17
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ grep "prime:   19" mse.txt | head -3
327685 =  5 65537   prime:   19
524288 =  2^19   prime:   19
524296 =  2^3 65537   prime:   19
```

===============